# Why is this object considered an rvalue?

Tags: c++, rvalue

Why is the object I'm passing to `ClassA`'s constructor considered an rvalue (temporary)? I'm aware that setting the parameter to `const` will make the error go away but I want to understand what's going on.

This behavior works fine for a function call but not for a constructor?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ClassA {
public:
   ClassA() {}
   ClassA(ClassA&) {}
};

void f(ClassA&) {}

int main() {
   ClassA a;

   // Invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'ClassA&' from an
   // rvalue of type 'ClassA'
   ClassA b = ClassA(a); 

   // Works fine
   f(a);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `f(ClassA(a))` is also invalid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rvalue here is the `ClassA(a)` expression.

```
ClassA b = ClassA(a);
```

That is copy-initialization, so it will attempt to call the copy constructor of `ClassA` with the result of `ClassA(a)`, which is an rvalue. You have declared the copy constructor to take a `ClassA&`, which can't bind to rvalues, so you get an error.

The best fix is, as you point out, to add `const` to the copy constructor so that it can bind to rvalues, but you could also use direct-initialization, or copy-initialization without the type conversion:

```
ClassA b (a);
ClassA b {a}; //C++11
ClassA b = a;
```

---

Note that although `ClassA b = ClassA(a);` requires a valid copy-constructor, the copy will likely be [elided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization). This is currently optional, but may be made [mandatory](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html) at some point.

Comment: `ClassA b = a;` Also works, and is also copy-construction.